# Terminate gstreamer from php

Tags: php, linux, gstreamer

I have a problem with terminating gstreamer which is running from php.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

So what do I'm trying to achieve:

I need start/stop video recording from web interface.

I wrote simple php script, which execute shell command:

**start.php**

```
<?php 
   $cmd = "sudo gst-launch-1.0 -v -e v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'image/jpeg,  width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1' ! videorate ! queue ! mux. alsasrc device="plughw:CARD=Device" ! queue ! mux. avimux name=mux ! filesink location=test.avi"
   shell_exec($cdm);
```

Everything works fine, apache user is sudoer, recording is started.

But, now I need to stop recording:

**stop.php**

```
<?php
$cmd = "sudo killall gst-launch-1.0";
shell_exec($cmd);
```

And this command takes too long time to terminate recording (about 33 seconds)

When I execute start command (e.g. sudo gst-launch-1.0 -v -e v4l2sr....) from command line, and then press Ctrl+c - it stops immediately.

Even if I'm trying to kill processes (**there are several processes with name gst-launch-1.0**) from command line (recording is running with start.php), it also takes about same time (30-33 seconds).
I've tried various commands: sudo killall gst-launch-1.0, sending SIGINIT to each pid with name gst-launch-1.0, kill -9 each pid, but it doesn't  help.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are recording a video, with option `-e`.
This option make GStreamer wait until finish its task before exit, thus prevent corrupt file.
In this case, when you kill gst-launch, due to option `-e` `gst-launch` will wait until the recorded data is written to disk completely. That is the reason for 30-33 seconds delay.
(Delay usually  gets longer for long recording)

**This behavior can be suppress by kill it twice (or Ctrl-C twice)**. The first kill (or Ctrl-C) will change the behavior of kill (Ctrl-C) back to normal, thus the second will actually kill program.
(You probably Ctrl-C twice so you do not see 30-33 seconds delay)

Comment: thank you for your answer. But I click once Ctrl-c in terminal and it exits immediately. Also, I issue kill command multiple times, and it doesn't help. And, as I know, if you send kill with -9 to process, it should exit immediately and process cannot override -9 signal.

Comment: Sorry, did not notice you had tried with kill -9. In this case, there is a theory, but I do not sure about it. Theory is: maybe gst-launch has transferred the job to system to finish writing data to disk (similar to `sync` command), and in this time it does not process your signal. I also meet this when record long video.